# How do I get Google search results from urlfetch in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-custom-search

I have been trying the following code

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com/#q=this+is+a+test");      
var contentText = response.getContentText();
      Logger.log(contentText);
      var thisdoc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody() ;
      thisdoc.setText(contentText);
     Logger.log(contentText.indexOf("About"));
```

But it only seems to return the header, and empty body, and none of the search results.  At minimum I should be able to see the "About xxx results" at the top of the browser but this doesn't appear in the text nor does the indexOf return a positive screen. I'm wondering if the search results are populated post page load meaning the body tag would indeed be empty and if so is there a workaround?

Edit: No it doesn't break the TOS as this is a GAFE app (which is a business app) and for business accounts they have both free and premium models of access to their API.

Comment: Investigate what the google page does by debugging it in chrome (see GET/POST network calls for example). Likely does an ajax so you could do the same call from gas

Comment: Check if you break their t.o.s. by doing the call directly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google provides an API for authorized searches, so don't fuss with scraping web pages.

For example, you can use the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest) with `UrlFetch()`.

From the script editor, go to `Resources -> Developer's Console Project... -> View Developer's Console`. Create a new key for Public API access. Follow the instructions from the Custom Search API docs to create a Custom search engine. Enter the key and ID into the script where indicated. (More details below.)

This example script will return an object containing the results of a successful search; you can navigate the object to pull out whatever info you want.

```js
/**
 * Use Google's customsearch API to perform a search query.
 * See https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest.
 *
 * @param {string} query   Search query to perform, e.g. "test"
 *
 * returns {object}        See response data structure at
 *                         https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#response
 */
function searchFor( query ) {

  // Base URL to access customsearch
  var urlTemplate = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=%KEY%&cx=%CX%&q=%Q%";

  // Script-specific credentials & search engine
  var ApiKey = "--get from developer's console--";
  var searchEngineID = "--get from developer's console--";

  // Build custom url
  var url = urlTemplate
    .replace("%KEY%", encodeURIComponent(ApiKey))
    .replace("%CX%", encodeURIComponent(searchEngineID))
    .replace("%Q%", encodeURIComponent(query));

  var params = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  // Perform search
  Logger.log( UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params) );  // Log query to be sent
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var respCode = response.getResponseCode();

  if (respCode !== 200) {
    throw new Error ("Error " +respCode + " " + response.getContentText());
  }
  else {
    // Successful search, log & return results
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log( "Obtained %s search results in %s seconds.",
               result.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults,
               result.searchInformation.formattedSearchTime);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
[15-05-04 18:26:35:958 EDT] {
  "headers": {
    "X-Forwarded-For": "216.191.234.70"
  },
  "useIntranet": false,
  "followRedirects": true,
  "payload": "",
  "method": "get",
  "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
  "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=--redacted--&cx=--redacted--&q=test"
}
[15-05-04 18:26:36:812 EDT] Obtained 132,000,000 search results in 0.74 seconds.
```

---

#### Identify your application to Google with API key

(excerpted from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction#identify_your_application_to_google_with_api_key).)

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2. Select a project, or create a new one.

   [image: screenshot]
3. In the sidebar on the left, expand **APIs & auth**. Next, click **APIs**. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the **Custom Search API**.

   [image: screenshot 2]

   . . .

   [image: screenshot 3]
4. In the sidebar on the left, select **Credentials**.

   Create your application's API key by clicking **Create new Key** under **Public API access**. For Google Script use, create a **Browser key**.
5. Once the **Key for browser applications** is created, copy the **API key** into your code.

#### Create a custom search engine

Follow the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630963). Once you've created your custom search engine, copy the **Search engine ID** into your code.

Comment: Thank you for this user friendly step by step description... I love it :-)