# Error 429 on scraping from Google search with Google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-search, urlfetch

I want to get the number of indexed pages for certain domains. Therefore I want to use the "site:" parameter and extract the number of results from the search result page.

I tried it with a Google-apps-script for Google spreadsheets:

```
function sampleFormula_4() {
  const url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Abenedikt-sahlmueller.de";
  
  try {
    const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    return html.match(/<div id="result-stats">(.+?)nobr>/)[1].trim();

  } catch (e) {
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    return html.match(/<div id="result-stats">(.+?)nobr>/)[1].trim();
  }
}
```

Google Spreadsheet gives me an error 429 - too many requests. I integrated a sleep-time of 5000ms, but Google Search still returns error 429.

All I need is the number of pages for certain URLs in Google's search results. Maybe there is a better way - I can't use the search-api for this as those pages are not part of my GSC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely Google Search is considering requests coming from `UrlFetch` as automated traffic and hence blocking them. From [the official docs](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en):

> #### What Google considers automated traffic
>
> - Sending searches from a robot, computer program, automated service, or search scraper

The same behaviour happens when using tools like `wget` or `curl`, for example.

Using the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest) is recommended.

#### Related:

- ["Unusual traffic from your computer network"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en)
- [How do I get Google search results from urlfetch in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29962902)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @lamblichus. Do you know if there is a way I can use the search-api to access data for domains I dont "own" as a propetry in GSC?

Comment: @s.Panse I don't think you need to "own" a domain for the API I mentioned. Just follow the steps mentioned in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/30041104/](this answer) and, once you have the search engine ID, use it to call [cse.list](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list) or [cse.siterestrict.list](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse.siterestrict/list), setting up `cx` to this ID.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll give it a try asap!

Comment: Hi @Iamblichus! I opened a "Google Apps Script", a new programmable search engine and added ID and API-key to the script. Then I called the function via Google Spreadsheet (= functionname (query)) but I dont get any reuslts back to Spreadsheet.
There is a  console ouput when I run the script directly and it looks okay to me. Can you give me a hint how I could use the output in spreadsheet?

Comment: Okay, I used `return (JSON.stringify(result));` to get some data to spreadhseet. As far as I understand I can't use "site:" in CSE to obtain the number of pages for a certain domain or host?

Comment: I think I got it: `aresult = JSON.stringify(result).match(/"totalResults":"(.+?)"/)[1].trim();` gives me the number of search results from CSE. I also had to update CSE settings in order to get the index-coverage from "site:": "All languages", "all countries", "search the whole web".

Comment: HI @Iamblichus! 
Do you by any chance have an idea on how I could save up some budget for api-calls? Right now I have to call a lot of data for every domain I enter - all I need is the number of page-results from a "page:"-query.

Comment: @s.Panse Can you provide the code related to the request you are making? Also, I'd suggest posting a new question for this, in order to give it more visibility.

Comment: Hi @Iamblichus, thanks agian for your help! I opened a neq question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66709930/. Lets see what happens. Have a nice weekend!